# Hibernate transient object exception

Tags: hibernate

I am struck with a problem while using hibernate.
 The situation is :

I  am creating a container and in that container i am adding 2 components. one component
  is a newly created component and the other one is already existing in the database.i am 
  getting an exception when i try to save the container. i get transient object exception.
  I tried giving cascade options as refresh but that doesnt work.

Thanks and Regards,
Rima Desai

Answer (score 2):

Transient object exception happen when a non-transient object (which is managed by the hibernate session) references an object that is not managed by the session. In your case I believe the container is referencing the new object.
did you call `session.Save(newObject);`?
Alternatively you can mark the relationship between the container as "cascade=save" to that saving it will cause the session to save its related objects.